# How long takes Nest client review process?

Tags: nest-api

I've been requesting more clients (from 1000 to 10000) for my nest application 10 days ago.
my process is "in review" for the past 5 days.
When can I espect to get the review complete ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can take from 5 days up to two weeks. It depends if your app passed through the [checklist for client review](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/client-review-best-practices#nest-client-review-checklist). Also make sure your app follows all the [UI/Marketing guidelines](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/ui-marketing-guidelines) so it won't slow down the process of the review and you will be able to get more user limits as soon as possible.